# Jenkins Job Builder: place Job in an existing folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I'd need to get started with JJB however one issue I'm facing is that I'm not able to upload jobs in an **existing** Folder (I'm using Cloudbees Folder plugin).
I've arranged an example based on an existing question available on SO:

```
- project:
name: playground

- job:

    name: sample_job 
    description: 'Automatically generated test'
    project-type: freestyle
    builders: 
      - shell: 'ls'
```

So the job should be loaded into the "playground" folder.
However the syntax seems uncorrect:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/home/francesco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/local_yaml.py", line 282, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 110, in compose_sequence_node
    while not self.check_event(SequenceEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 393, in parse_block_sequence_entry
    "expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block collection
  in "/home/francesco/git/tests-jobs/jobs/test.yaml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '?'
  in "/home/francesco/git/tests-jobs/jobs/test.yaml", line 2, column 1
```

The existing answers provided so far on this question are related to folders created as part of JJB. In my case the folder has been already created ahead.
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@francesco, Basically you have to use jobs, job template to create a jenkins job. I have tried this based on your question and able to execute without failures. Check if this answers your question.

```
---
  - project:
      name: playground
      jobs:
        - sample_job

  - job-template:
      name: sample_job
      description: 'Automatically generated test'
      project-type: freestyle
      builders:
        - shell: 'ls'
```

Comment: Thanks! actually I figured out what I needed was to place a job in a view. I can do it by configuring the single view and assigning the jobs to it. Thanks anyway.